# Error "Friend Overloads Sub InitVars()' has multiple definitions with identical signatures."?

Tags: vb.net

I am using visual studio 2013 to build my database.

Yesterday I was working on my form with 6 tabs total. From time to time I haved copied some textbox or combobox from 1 to my 6 or 7 tab. I was to lazy to create some blank textbox or combobox and that's why I did it. Suddenly I get this error

> 'Friend Overloads Sub InitVars()' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.
>
> 'Friend Overloads Sub InitVars(initTable As Boolean)' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.
>
> 'Friend Property Connection As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.

[image]

and I can't open ANY form from my database! I suddenly have 102 errors?!

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Do a Ctrl-F find at the solution level for "Sub InitVars" Find the multiple definition and remove it. Also, 102 errors is just a max value displayed - it's likely since your dependent DataSet project couldn't compile due to an error or two that every reference to it will result in an error.

Comment: Copy/Pasting controls is **bad**. You should be using a `UserControl` for that. Follows encapsulation in `OOP` setting.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain me this part "You should be using a UserControl for that. Follows encapsulation in OOP setting."? Thank you. Adi